# How neo4j handles SQL and cypher?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I observed neo4j it is handling both SQL and Cypher. I wanted to know how is it working ? How it is going to translate and then gave output is graph visualization.

I have checked graph algorithms but still confused in its translation and identification of query.

Comment: Where did you observe that Neo4j handles SQL?

Comment: from that blog https://medium.com/neo4j/using-the-bi-connector-to-query-neo4j-with-sql-372eacb08fbc

Comment: You can see that this is a custom plugin for Neo4j that translates SQL to Cypher: https://neo4j.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-neo4j-bi-connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j does not handle SQL. It uses the Cypher query language only: [Cypher Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/). As Tomaž Bratanič pointed out in the comment there are several tools that are able to translate SQL to Cypher, such as the BI connector included with Neo4j enterprise.

While some of them will get you relatively far, you should really dive into [Cypher](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/).

A bunch of Graph algorithms are implemented in [Neo4j GDS](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/), that are run inside Neo4j, not external like the above mentioned BI connector. Those can be called both from Cypher or with external clients.